# MVC Token API Very Slow

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-web-api

I have a ASP.NET MVC Web API application that implements a /token method. This returns the token using standard code.

We have noticed that even after the app is deployed on "always-on" on Azure it takes a very long time for the token to be issued.

Is there something that we are missing in code/ application config/ or Azure config to make returning the token faster.

thanks in advance.

Code from Start.Auth.cs

```
 public partial class Startup
    {
        public static OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthOptions { get; private set; }

        public static string PublicClientId { get; private set; }

        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Configure the db context and user manager to use a single instance per request
            app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);

            // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
            // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
            app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

            // Configure the application for OAuth based flow. Do it only once!
            if (OAuthOptions == null)
            {
                PublicClientId = "self";
                OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
                {
                    TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/login"),
                    Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
                    AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1), //.FromMinutes(5),
                // AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
                AllowInsecureHttp = true,
                };
            }

            // Enable the application to use bearer tokens to authenticate users
            app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to include the code in question, otherwise it is very difficult to offer any advice.

Comment: if it is only one time after deployment, chek this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-staged-publishing

Comment: no this happens always